# Rails + Ubuntu + MySQL = Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04

I have XAMPP installed on Ubuntu 12.04 and it all works.
I've also been using Rails for a while with PostgreSQL and it also worked fine.

Today, I tried creating a new app using mysql with `mysql2` gem, and got an error while running `rake db:create`.

I first checked the other Rails/MySQL questions on SO, and will say:

1. MySQL is running
2. Using `mysql2` gem
3. DB config looks correct (to me)
4. `database.yml` using `socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Error:

```
/opt/lampp/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18: symbol SSL_accept, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.so
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/media/fat64/work/_active/josephzidell_rails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/media/fat64/work/_active/josephzidell_rails/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/media/fat64/work/_active/josephzidell_rails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/wwc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: do you have the ssl libs installed?

Comment: Not sure. If not, what's the command?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing SSL libs using:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

You can check the path that it has been installed in using:

```
apt-file list libssl-dev
```

you may need to install apt-file first by running:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Comment: MattW, thanks for your help. `libssl-dev` was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby 2.0.0 got problem with OpenSSL 1.0.1f

Check [How can I ensure that Ruby uses an OpenSSL not vulnerable to Heartbleed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993541/how-can-i-ensure-that-ruby-uses-an-openssl-not-vulnerable-to-heartbleed) and you will realize that your Ruby's OpenSSL lib is not up-to-date

Follow these command (credit: https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq) 
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.0.0 \ 
    --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
    --verify-downloads 1

The new installed Ruby 2.0.0 on your machine will got the final OpenSSL version (1.0.1g), which also patched for the Heart Bleed.